Created consistent caption formatting between figures and flextables in rmd html output
I am having trouble getting my captions for figures and tables having consistent formatting when knitting a Rmd to html2 output from the bookdown package.  I have tried applying different methods from documentation here and various forums posts on stack overflow but none seem to make any difference.  A few examples of things I tried without success below. Bonus points for solving the same problem if switching to pdf output.
---
title: "Caption Testing"

output:
  bookdown::html_document2: 
    toc: false
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: false
    self_contained: true
    mode: selfcontained
---

<style type="text/css">
  body{
  font-size: 16pt;
  
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
  .caption{
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
  caption{
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold
}
</style>



<style type="caption">
  caption{
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold
}
</style>



```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, out.width='100%' )

library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

set_flextable_defaults(font.size=16)
```
## Placeholder Heading

Want to produce html document that has consistent formatting between figure and table captions.  Multiple approaches applied none seem to have any effect.  I have been avoiding set_caption(as_paragraph(etc...)) as I would prefer to set as a more global option and not having to copy/paste options for each table and consistency with how figure labels are formatted where the second css style code(.caption) gives desired result.

```{r figure, fig.cap="Example ggplot" , fig.asp=1}
mtcars %>%
  
ggplot(aes(cyl, wt) )+geom_point()
```


More text

```{r table1, echo=FALSE}

head(mtcars,10) %>%
  flextable() %>%
    set_caption("No extra formatting")


```

More text



```{r table2, echo=FALSE, tab.cap="Set in chunk options using tab.cap.style=.caption" ,tab.cap.style=".caption"}

head(mtcars,10) %>%
  flextable() 


```
More text

```{r table3, echo=FALSE, tab.cap="Set in chunk options using tab.cap.style=caption" ,tab.cap.style="caption"}

head(mtcars,10) %>%
  flextable() 


```
More text

```{r table4, echo=FALSE }

head(mtcars,10) %>%
  flextable() %>%
    set_caption(caption = "Set in set_caption style=caption", style = "caption")


```

More text

```{r table5, echo=FALSE }

head(mtcars,10) %>%
  flextable() %>%
    set_caption(caption = "Set in set_caption style=.caption", style = ".caption")


```
More text


```{r table6, echo=FALSE }

head(mtcars,10) %>%
  flextable() %>%
    set_caption(caption = "Set in set_caption html_classes=.caption",html_classes = ".caption")


```


Your custom CSS styles will not be applied to the flextable captions because flextables are rendered in the shadow-dom's, which uses its own separate CSS styles.
However, you can append custom CSS style to a flextable instance using
ft <- flextable::set_table_properties(
  x = ft, 
  opts_html = list(
    extra_css = 'caption {
      font-size: 16pt;
      font-weight: bold;
    }'
  )
)

Then this ft will be rendered with 16pt bold caption text in bookdown html_document.
To apply custom CSS styles to all flextables, use set_flextable_defaults(extra_css = ...):
set_flextable_defaults(extra_css = 'caption {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}')


I confirm the solution and explanation provided by @FaniX is the correct one
